# Test for similar movements in time series

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, similarities

I'm currently doing a research and I am using multiple time series about the CPI of certain product categories in China.
I want to measure which time series acts in the same way as the CPI of milk products.
I first used Euclidean distance and Dynamic Time Warping, but I just realised that there might be time series that act in similar ways as the CPI of milk, but always in a much bigger or smaller sense (so that we could model this specific time series as: constant * CPI milk products. For instance, I could imagine a time series to always have only 10% of the same positive/negative effect as CPI of milk, so that the model becomes 0.1*CPImilk.)

Is there a measure for testing the similarities in movements?

Comment: The question is not very clear. What do you mean by similarity/ies?

Comment: I want to measure whether there is a time series that 'reacts' in the same way as the time series of CPI milk. For instance, when CPI of milk reacts positively, then the other time series as well :)

Comment: The question isn't completely clear to me but this reference may offer one approach to addressing it. Meng, et al.'s paper *Symmetric thermal optimal path and time-dependent lead-lag relationship: Novel statistical tests and application to UK and US real-estate and monetary policies* is a unique approach to teasing out directionality in pairs of time series. It's worth a look (https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14697688.2016.1241424?needAccess=true&journalCode=rquf20).